# 関数オブジェクトを作るときに暗黙のパラメータをどう渡すか

Tags: scala

関数オブジェクトを作るときに暗黙のパラメータをどう渡すべきなのでしょうか。

次のように、何も指定しないとエラーになります（val process = の部分）。

```
case class Cache(key: Int, value: String)

class Processor {
  val process = processF _  // could not find implicit value for parameter cache: this.Cache

  private def processF()(implicit cache: Cache): String = cache.value
}

object Main {
  def run() {
    implicit val cache = Cache(10, "hello")

    val processor = new Processor
    processor.process()
  }
}

Main.run
```

こんなかんじで書ければいいのですが、うまくいきません。

```
val process: ()(implicit cache: Cache) => String = processF _ // シンタックスエラー
```

そもそも可能かどうかもわかりませんが、どういったアプローチが有効かお教え願えますでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

質問者さんの意図に合致するかどうかわかりませんが、コンストラクタの引数を`implicit`にして渡してやるというのはどうでしょう。
（簡単のため`Main`オブジェクトを`App`にしました。)

```
case class Cache(key: Int, value: String)

class Processor(implicit c: Cache) {
  //implicit val cache2 = Cache(20, "hola")
  val process = processF _
  private def processF()(implicit cache: Cache): String = cache.value
}

object Main extends App {
  implicit val cache = Cache(10, "hello")
  val processor = new Processor
  println(processor.process())
}
```

`cache2`のように`val`の前に`implicit`があればそれを見に行ってくれるようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます、そう書けるのですね。勉強になりました。

Processor が class ではなく trait の場合には別のテクニックを考え出す必要がありそうですね。もし何か思いつかれましたらお願いします。